# Set locale via default_url_options for Rails tests (Rails 6 and newer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Is there a reliable way to set the locale via `default_url_options` for Rails tests (controller and system tests) globally, without having to pass the locale manually to url helpers?

Prior to Rails 6.0.1, this used to work:

```
# Set locale via default_url_options
class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller tests should respect the `default_url_options` set in the `ApplicationController` anyway.

To use a default locale for system tests, for Rails 6, adding this snippets to the `test_helper.rb` file is enough, as stated in the question:

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
end
```

For Rails 6.0.1 and 6.0.2, one needs to instead add this beast to the `application_system_test_case.rb` file:

```
  # See actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/system_test_case.rb
  def initialize(*)
    super
    @proxy_route = if ActionDispatch.test_app
      Class.new do
        include ActionDispatch.test_app.routes.url_helpers
        include ActionDispatch.test_app.routes.mounted_helpers

        def url_options
          default_url_options.merge(host: Capybara.app_host, locale: I18n.locale)
        end
      end.new
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

Comment: With Rails 6.1.3, I used the second option but had to replace `@proxy_route` with `@url_helpers`

Answer (score 1):

Following this [Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/546) you may be able to access `default_url_options` without a monkey patch:

```rb
ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.app.default_url_options[:locale] = I18n.locale
```

However I would suggest manually passing the locale param every time.

I had the same issue with an application and ended up manually setting the param in all tests. It's tedious the first time but it ends up making all calls clearer and helps rely less on code specifically for the test suite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately setting it this way doesn't work either with Rails 6.0.2. 

I think system tests should respect `default_url_options` set via the application controller though, as they are part of the … well system. 

But manually setting the locale param in all tests might be the only option to being able to finally upgrade from 6.0.0. I already started changing all system tests in a separate branch a while ago, with about 900 tests to change  …

Comment: You may find it less tedious to write a program to help you. For example you could write a RuboCop rule with auto correct, like https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/rails/http_positional_arguments.rb ; Even if it takes as much time you'll have learned something, I guess ;)

Comment: Yes, that would be a nice way to approach this. In the meantime, I actually found a way to set default_url_options for the system tests (controller test respect the setting in the ApplicationController anyway). Will post it later.