# Rails default_url_options conflicts with params in path/url-helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-i18n

In my Rails-6.1.4 application, I have introduced the `locale` filter in the [routing-filter](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter) Gem to allow a language-locale in URL-paths like `/en/articles` (for locale "en"). Then, I find path helpers fail when `params` parameter (or any optional parameters) is given.

Here is a demonstrative example of failure in testing (minitest) at `article_url()` path helper for the model `Article` with a model instance of `@article`:

```rb
 # test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb
patch article_url(@article, params: { article: my_hash })
```

resulting in

```
# Error output
ArticlesControllerTest#test_should_update:
DRb::DRbRemoteError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles",
 :locale=>#<Article id: 805413029, ...>}, missing required keys: [:id]
 (ActionController::UrlGenerationError)
    test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb:58:in `block in <class:ArticlesControllerTest>'
```

Basically, the main argument for the path helper `@article`, which is a model instance, seems to be somehow interpreted as a locale(!) by the path helper.
I should note I find path helpers work fine when the `param` (or whatever) option is not given. So, it causes a problem only when an extra parameter is given.

What is the appropriate solution for this?

---

My setting is as follows.

```rb
 # test_helper.rb  (as recommended in the reference of routing-filter)
RoutingFilter.active = false

 # application_controller.rb
def default_url_options
  Rails.application.default_url_options = Rails.application.routes.default_url_options =
   { locale: I18n.locale }
end

 # config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  filter :locale
  
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja|fr/ do # [EDIT] This scope should be removed;
                                           # It is unnecessary and is sometimes harmful 
                                           # as the locale in the path may be doubled. 
    resources :articles
  end
end
```

Here I am using the [head (8d1f1da) of the master branch](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter/commit/8d1f1da79c4db786e8baeda586a8d790e23712bf) for routing-filter because the current [RubyGems.org version (0.6.3)](https://rubygems.org/gems/routing-filter/versions/0.6.3) for it is known not to work with Rails 6.1 (see [Issue 75](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter/issues/75)).

---

In fact, I have managed to find a dirty workaround:

```rb
article_url(@article, {params: { article: my_hash }}.merge(
  ApplicationController.new.default_url_options))
```

However, this means this `Hash#merge` has to be written every time a helper is used with an optional parameter…  That would be extremely tedious in practice, where there can be hundreds or thousands of such sentences in the test suite, and it is of course against the DRY principle.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, *in addition to* setting `default_url_options` in `application_controller.rb`, set it in `config/routes.rb` for the *test* environment as

```rb
 # config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  filter :locale
    default_url_options(locale: I18n.locale) if Rails.env.test?
```

It seems this is the way to set `default_url_options` in Rails 6.1 (**[EDIT]** the setting in `application_controller.rb` is still required for the *development* environment; the **test** environment demands this setting). This works fine in both test and development environments *except* when path helpers are called out of the context, I mean not from a Controller or in Views, in which case the OP's *dirty workaround* solved the issue:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.article_url(
  article,
  {only_path: true}.merge(ApplicationController.new.default_url_options)
)
```

### Background

Gem [routing-filter](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter) works by modifying a path as if the locale word (like "en") contained in the (head of the) path is passed as a URL parameter (like `?locale=en`), while removing the locale part from the path. Therefore, to set `default_url_options` is the right strategy.

It is true "Setting the Locale from URL Params" in [Rail's official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) does tell, at the time of writing (Rails-6.1.4), that
`default_url_options` is set in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`
to set a default locale URL-parameter.

But perhaps the description is outdated — I mean, not accurate in Rails 6.1 any more?

Note that it seems `default_url_options` has been causing a trouble in Rails 6; see [Set locale via default_url_options for Rails tests (Rails 6 and newer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295991/set-locale-via-default-url-options-for-rails-tests-rails-6-and-newer).